# NSMangedObject subclass method called constantly after changing NSFetchedResultsController NSPredicate

Tags: ios, core-data, swift2

I've been stuck with this and cannot find the culprit. I will try to include as much useful code that I can. See bottom for TL;DR version.

**IDEA**
User opens the app, you can find restaurants in a certain city OR set it to find the restaurants near your location (assuming you allowed the app to see your location). If you set the city, then the NSFetchedResultsController performs a fetch with a certain `NSPredicate`. When you tap on the button to find the restaurants near you, it changed the `NSPredicate` and executes the fetch again.

**SET UP**
1) When my `UIViewController` is loaded, it called a method on a subclass of `NSUserDefaults` to grab the user's current location.
2) This method tells a `CLLocationManager` object to start updating the user's location, once it has updated the location, the `didUpdateLocations` method gets called.
3) Since I have `.desiredAccuracy` set to `kCLLocationAccuracyBest` the `didUpdateLocations` method gets called often, so I set a timer to perform a method called `updateRestaurantDistance` which performs a fetch on the main `NSManagedObjectContext` and retrieves all the restaurants in the database.
4) A loop iterates through each restaurant and calls a method to set the restaurant's distance from the user.
5) Once the loop is finished, I save the context with the updated values.

**ISSUE**
Everything runs fine when I start the app, and once the fetch from `4)` is finished iterating through each item, I can tap the button that fetches the restaurants that are near me.
However, if the iterations from `4)` aren't finished, and I tap the button that finds the restaurants near me, the iterations finish, but the context is not saved (I have `print` statements set up) and the method that updates the restaurant distance is called infinitely blocking the main thread and making the UI unusable.

**CODE**
- UIViewController

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //configure properties
    //core data
    context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

    //fetch controller
    fetchController.delegate = self

    //default values
    user = User()
    self.user.getCurrentLocation()

 }
//method that is called when the button to filter restaurants near user is tapped
func nearMe() {

        restaurantPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "(distance < %f AND distance > %f) AND SUBQUERY(specials,$s, ($s.type LIKE %@ OR $s.type LIKE %@) AND $s.day LIKE %@).@count > 0",
            user.doubleForKey(UserData.MaxDistance.rawValue), 0.01, typeQuery!, "Combo", day)

        fetchController.fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [distSort,nameSort,citySort]
        do {
            try fetchController.performFetch()
        } catch {
            print("Error fetching when sorting by near me")
        }
        tableView.reloadData()

    }
```

The `User` class that has the method to get location

```
func getCurrentLocation() {
        //ask for access to location (if not given)
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }

        //if allowed, start checking for location
        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }

    }
```

The CLLocationDelegate

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        // get coordintes
        if let locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location?.coordinate {
            //check if timer has started
            if timer == nil {
                timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "updateRestaurantDistance", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
            } else {
                timer?.invalidate()
                timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "updateRestaurantDistance", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
            }

            //stop updating since we're done
            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

        }
    }
```

Update location method

```
func updateRestaurantDistance() {
        let fetch = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Restaurant")
        let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
        do {
            let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetch) as! [Restaurant]
            for result in results {
                print(results.indexOf(result))
                result.getDistance()
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error updating restaurant distances from UserClass")
        }
        do {
            try context.save()
            print("saved context")
        } catch {
            print("error saving context while updating restaurant distance: \(error)")
        }

    }
```

The Restaurant methods

```
//This method gets called infinitely and I have no idea why  
func getDistance() {
        print("getDistance")
        guard CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .AuthorizedWhenInUse else {
            return
        }
        self.distance = self.getDistanceFromRestaurant()

    }

    func getDistanceFromRestaurant() -> CLLocationDistance {
        let user = User()
        guard CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .AuthorizedWhenInUse else {
            return Double(0)
        }
        let longitude = user.doubleForKey(UserData.Longitute.rawValue)
        let latitude = user.doubleForKey(UserData.Latitude.rawValue)
        guard abs(longitude) + abs(latitude) > 0 else {
            return Double(0)
        }
        let loc = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
        let selfLoc = CLLocation(latitude: Double(self.latitude), longitude: Double(self.longitude))
        return loc.distanceFromLocation(selfLoc) / 1000
    }
```

Happy to add more if needed, thank you!

**EDIT**: Seems that it gets to `try context.save()` in `updateRestaurantDistance()` and starts the loop there (aka it doesn't get to the `print` statement

**EDIT 2**: TL;DR Code version:
This updates the restaurant's distance to the user, `try`s are in do-catch blocks but removed for simplicity

```
func updateRestaurantDistance() {
    let fetch = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Restaurant")
    let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

    let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetch) as! [Restaurant]
    for result in results {
        result.getDistance()
    }
    try context.save()

}  

func getDistance() {
    self.distance = 10 // method to calculate distance is called, but for simplicity set to 10
}
```

While `updateResturantDistance` is running, I cannot change the `NSPredicate` to anything with a `distance` attribute and perform a fetch for my `NSFetchedResultsController` i.e:

```
predicate = NSPredicate(format: "distance < %f", 10)
fetchController.fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
try fetchController.performFetch
```

doesn't work, but

```
predicate = NSPredicate(format: "city LIKE %@", "New York")
fetchController.fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
try fetchController.performFetch
```

works

Answer (score 0):

Either

- disable the UI control that causes the reload until everything is finished

or

- keep a Bool variable around indicating if you are looping through the locations. When the control is hit, change this variable. In the loop check the variable and abort if it has changed and start from scratch without saving.

Comment: Any idea what is happening in the background? I am curious as to why this happens. For the time being I'll do like you said and hack a quick `UIActivityIndicatorView` to disable the button.

Comment: You have posted way too much code to analyze this. If you reduce it to the minimal necessary lines that describe your problem, I will take a look.

Comment: thanks, I updated my question with very minimal amount of code - see the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 0):

OH. MY. GOODNESS.
WOW
So let's recall getters and setters. In most programming languages that aren't like swift i.e Java, you must create them with methods i.e

```
private var distance = 1
getDistance() -> Int {
   return self.distance
}
```

But in swift, this isn't necessary. Anyways, turns out my `getDistance` method was being called for my `NSPredicate`. I changed the name of the method to `getRestaurantDistance` and everything runs as expected. Do not be like my and name methods that would also be named the getter and setter.